# A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected - concatenate them

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following column definition within Power BI:

```
NameLookup = LOOKUPVALUE(pet[fullName],pet[user],users[_id])
```

It gives the following error though

> A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

Is it possible to concatenate the rows into a single string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is searching, this did the trick:

```
CONCATENATEX(FILTER(ALL(Pet), pet[user] = users[_id]), pet[fullName],", ")
```